# Изменение вложенного dict python

Tags: python, словари

Всем привет.
Имею nested dict следующего вида:
{u'314389295': {u'Login': u'John', u'Secret': u'qweetgdsjre123'}}

После выполнения некоторого кода мне нужно заменить элемент 314389295:

```
with open('project/users.txt', 'r+') as data_file:    
  for line in data_file:
    for k, v in json.loads(line).items():
       print(v['Secret'])
    if v['Secret'] == Token:
        Name = (v['Login'])
        text = json.loads(line)
        text.update( {uid} ) - uid это первый элемент
        data_file.seek(0)
        json.dump(text, data_file)
```

Получаю ошибку `TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence`
Что логично, так как вместо key: value пишу только один элемент.
Как с текущим кодом, можно сделать апдейт?
Спасибо.

Comment: что долно получиься в результате ?

Comment: В результате должен 1 элемент (314389295 - в моем случае) поменяться на новое значение.

Comment: text[k].update( новое значение) ?

Comment: `text[k].update( username )
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`
`text[k].update(str(username))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`
В любом случае ошибка